# Why is system.exception not serializable in send message shape?

Tags: c#, serialization, exception, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am testing the exception handling of my BizTalk 2010 orchestration. The orchestration has one scope shape with one catch shape attached to it. 
The scope shape's transaction type is set to 'NONE' so I can work with the .NET exception.  Inside the catch is a construct message shape with a message assignment shape. The message assignment shape is using the active message type from the receive shape.

When the orchestration runs it suspends on the send message shape. The error is:

> Type System.Xml.XmlDocument in Assembly System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx is not marked as serializable.

My project is set up such that for testing purposes I can process either an incoming BizTalk message or an XML file (via the test editor.)
I can take the XML that is submitted to the receive shape, save it as an XML file and process the XML file.

To test the exception handling I have purposely
coded a database insert that will fail.  The full database error is written to a log file and a new exception is throw with a message like this: 
*Failed to process BLAH request to completion - Message Processor - Image ID: ABC Note ID: XYZ.* When running the XML file, the application throws the error
in the expected place and the error is caught back at the test editor.  I am able to serialize the error message in the test editor function.

However, when running from BizTalk I get the error.  A correlation set has been defined with these properties:
*BTS.ReceivePortName,ErrorReport.ErrorType,ErrorReport.InboundTransportLocation.*
The code in the assign shape is as follows.

```
msgFail = InputMsg;
msgFail(ErrorReport.ErrorType) = "FailedMessage";
msgFail(ErrorReport.Description) = ex.Message;
msgFail(ErrorReport.FailureCategory) = 0;
msgFail(ErrorReport.FailureCode) = "";
msgFail(ErrorReport.InboundTransportLocation) = InputMsg(BTS.InboundTransportLocation);
msgFail(ErrorReport.RoutingFailureReportID) = System.Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid());
```

msgFail is the message I am trying to send.

InputMsg is the active message type from the initial receive shape.  It is a multi-part message type tied to a schema that validates.

`ex` is the `exception object` name in the catch shape.  It is of type System.Exception.

I've read many posts about how to set the properties for the scope and catch shapes to be able to use the exception object, but it is still not working.
I am making an assumption that since I can serialize the error message when running from the XML file that my problem is with how my orchestration is getting the exception.

Comment: are you sure that its a vanilla exception?

Comment: @SOreadytohelp, Thanks. Not sure what you mean by "vanilla". If the only change I make to the incoming message is to have the comment text under the max for the database column, the orchestrations runs to completion and sends it's message to the external system, so I'm pretty sure of when and how the exception is being thrown.

Comment: You would only need to define the Exception object, ex, in the hander itself, not at the Scope level.  But, the Serialization warning is not about an Exception (title) it's about XmlDocument which is well understood.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Johns-305, thanks.  Not sure what you would like clarified.  Yes, ex is defined in the Catch Exception shape - Exception Object Name = ex.  Exception Object Type = System.SystemException.    I don't know what xmlDocument it's referring to.  Is it the incoming message from the receive shape?

Comment: It would be any XmlDocument that's not in an Atomic Scope/Orchestrations.  In the title, you're asking about System.Exception not being serializeable, but that's now what the post is asking about.

Comment: @Johns-305   Sorry, this is my first BizTalk project.  According to what I have read, you have to specify 'NONE' for transaction type in the scope if you want to get .NET exceptions.  As far as being serializeable, there are only two message shapes being used in this orchestration when an exception occurs,  The incoming message type is tied to a schema.  The Send Error message shape is also using the incoming message type. So what xml wouldn't be serializeable?

Comment: @ktri The transaction on the scope can either be None or Long Running to have an exception block and to be able to catch exceptions.  You can only not have an exception block for a Atomic scope.  Have you tried commenting out lines in your assign shape to determine which line is causing the error?  Is it the msgFail = InputMsg; ?

Comment: On a different note, do you have the  Do you have the ESB Toolkit installed?

Comment: What Message Type is msgFail?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf  msgFail is of type InputMsg .  InputMsg is a multipart message with its message part type that of the receive message schema.  That schema validates as does the instance of the schema I am trying to process.  No ESBToolkit available on the servers.  Not sure how to comment out anything in the assign shape.  There is only one active message type.

Comment: It is c# code, so a double forward slash to comment out a line.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, sorry I should have been more clear. MsgFail has to be assigned to a message type that is already active, right? There is no other message in my orchstration. I tried making a test orchestration with the same message type an port setup. Instead of calling my normal method from the first expression shape I just created a variable of system exception and assigned the error message to it. Same catch, assign and send.  Runs fine. That should prove that my message type is fine, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ESB Toolkit installed you can use that to create your fault messages.

e.g

```
eSBFault = Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionMgmt.CreateFaultMessage();
eSBFault.FailureCategory= "General System Exception";
eSBFault.FaultCode = "500";
eSBFault.FaultDescription = orchestrationName + ": " + ex.Message;
eSBFault.FaultSeverity = Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.FaultSeverity.Error;
eSBFault.Scope = "Scope Name";   
Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionMgmt.AddMessage(eSBFault, InputMsg);
```

Note 1: orchestrationName is a variable that was set earlier in the Orchestration

```
orchestrationName = Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.RootService.Name;
```

Note 2: Your msgFail is eSBFault in this example, but you can call it msgFail as well.  It is of Message Type Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.Schemas.Faults.FaultMessage